# Mule JMS HornetQ connection

Tags: spring, mule, jboss7.x, hornetq

I am trying to connect to a remote HornetQ on jboss7.1 . The configuration looks like below:

```
<spring:beans>
    <util:map id="jmsProperties">
        <spring:entry key="host" value="xxxxxx"/>
        <spring:entry key="port" value="61613"/>
    </util:map>

    <spring:bean name="transportConfiguration"
                 class="org.hornetq.api.core.TransportConfiguration">
        <spring:constructor-arg value="org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory"/>
        <spring:constructor-arg ref="jmsProperties"/>
    </spring:bean>

    <spring:bean name="connectionFactory"
                 class="org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQJMSConnectionFactory">
        <spring:constructor-arg index="0" value="false"/>
        <spring:constructor-arg index="1" ref="transportConfiguration"/>
        <spring:property name="reconnectAttempts" value="5"/>
        <spring:property name="retryInterval" value="5000"/>
    </spring:bean>
    <spring:bean id="testJMS"
        class="com.TestJMS"
        scope="prototype" />

</spring:beans>


<jms:connector name="hornetq-connector" specification="1.1" connectionFactory-ref="connectionFactory" />
```

while starting my tomcat server, I am getting the below exception. Not sure whats the issue is. I can telnet to the host on that port. Any suggestions would be helpful.

SEVERE: **Timed out waiting for response when sending packet 30**
org.mule.retry.RetryPolicyExhaustedException: Timed out waiting for response when sending packet 30
    at org.mule.retry.policies.AbstractPolicyTemplate.execute(AbstractPolicyTemplate.java:105)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector.connect(AbstractConnector.java:1616)
    at org.mule.transport.jms.JmsConnector.connect(JmsConnector.java:458)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector.start(AbstractConnector.java:428)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.DefaultLifecyclePhase.applyLifecycle(DefaultLifecyclePhase.java:225)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager$RegistryLifecycleCallback.onTransition(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:276)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.invokePhase(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:155)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:126)
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistryBroker.fireLifecycle(AbstractRegistryBroker.java:80)
    at org.mule.registry.MuleRegistryHelper.fireLifecycle(MuleRegistryHelper.java:120)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:94)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:90)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.invokePhase(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:72)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:64)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleContext.start(DefaultMuleContext.java:255)
    at org.mule.config.builders.MuleXmlBuilderContextListener.initialize(MuleXmlBuilderContextListener.java:100)
    at org.mule.config.builders.MuleXmlBuilderContextListener.contextInitialized(MuleXmlBuilderContextListener.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1566)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1556)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Timed out waiting for response when sending packet 30
    at org.hornetq.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.sendBlocking(ChannelImpl.java:276)
    at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.createSessionInternal(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:695)
    at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.createSession(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:264)
    at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnection.authorize(HornetQConnection.java:601)
    at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:684)
    at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnection(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:119)
    at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnection(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:114)
    at org.mule.transport.jms.Jms11Support.createConnection(Jms11Support.java:68)
    at org.mule.transport.jms.JmsConnector.createConnection(JmsConnector.java:433)
    at org.mule.transport.jms.JmsConnector.doConnect(JmsConnector.java:515)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector$5.doWork(AbstractConnector.java:1556)
    at org.mule.retry.policies.AbstractPolicyTemplate.execute(AbstractPolicyTemplate.java:67)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: HornetQException[errorCode=3 message=Timed out waiting for response when sending packet 30]
    ... 41 more

org.mule.retry.RetryPolicyExhaustedException: Timed out waiting for response when sending packet 30
    at org.mule.retry.policies.AbstractPolicyTemplate.execute(AbstractPolicyTemplate.java:105)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector.connect(AbstractConnector.java:1616)
    at org.mule.transport.jms.JmsConnector.connect(JmsConnector.java:458)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector.start(AbstractConnector.java:428)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.DefaultLifecyclePhase.applyLifecycle(DefaultLifecyclePhase.java:225)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager$RegistryLifecycleCallback.onTransition(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:276)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.invokePhase(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:155)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:126)
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistryBroker.fireLifecycle(AbstractRegistryBroker.java:80)
    at org.mule.registry.MuleRegistryHelper.fireLifecycle(MuleRegistryHelper.java:120)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:94)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:90)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.invokePhase(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:72)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:64)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleContext.start(DefaultMuleContext.java:255)
    at org.mule.config.builders.MuleXmlBuilderContextListener.initialize(MuleXmlBuilderContextListener.java:100)
    at org.mule.config.builders.MuleXmlBuilderContextListener.contextInitialized(MuleXmlBuilderContextListener.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1566)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1556)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Timed out waiting for response when sending packet 30
    at org.hornetq.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.sendBlocking(ChannelImpl.java:276)
    at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.createSessionInternal(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:695)
    at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.createSession(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:264)
    at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnection.authorize(HornetQConnection.java:601)
    at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:684)
    at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnection(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:119)
    at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnection(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:114)
    at org.mule.transport.jms.Jms11Support.createConnection(Jms11Support.java:68)
    at org.mule.transport.jms.JmsConnector.createConnection(JmsConnector.java:433)
    at org.mule.transport.jms.JmsConnector.doConnect(JmsConnector.java:515)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector$5.doWork(AbstractConnector.java:1556)
    at org.mule.retry.policies.AbstractPolicyTemplate.execute(AbstractPolicyTemplate.java:67)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: HornetQException[errorCode=3 message=Timed out waiting for response when sending packet 30]
    ... 41 more

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you miss some of the Mule jars. Make sure you follow teh instructions in: [Deploying Mule as a Service to Tomcat](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Deploying+Mule+as+a+Service+to+Tomcat).